# Error when invoking macro

Tags: macros, jupyter-notebook, julia

My task is to do harmonic mean using macros.
So I wrote something like that:

```
macro mean(arr)
    ex = Expr(:call, :/, 1, arr[1])
    for i = 2:length(arr)
         ex = Expr(:call, :+, ex, Expr(:call, :/, 1, arr[i]))
    end
    println(arr[1])
    Expr(:call, :/, length(arr), ex)
end
```

and then executed with 4 arguments

```
@mean(2,2,5,7)
```

which caused error:

```
MethodError: no method matching @mean(::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64)
```

So here comes my question: what is wrong and how should I correct this?
It is worth to mention that this program works for my friend, but not for me.

Comment: You need to write `macro mean(arr...)`. Also it would be good to check if `arr` is not empty inside the macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you inserted values as multiple arguments and not as an array. You should do `@mean([2, 2, 5, 7])`